# How to draw using System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I've done a bit of similar work using Swing in Java, but have never had any need to try doing the same thing in C#. Looking briefly online I can't seem to find any consise tutorials on how to using the simple drawing tools. Can anybody point me in a good direction?

Also, I'm looking to draw straight lines and rectangle boxes onto a custom user control that isn't fixed in size. This means that when the control is resized in the Visual Studio UI, it needs to repaint the lines accordingly to account for the new control dimensions. How might I go about doing this as well?

Thanks

Comment: This one seems like an easy intro http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/winforms-drawing-cs.aspx

Answer (score 4):

check out [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for basic graphics control on windows.

Here is a [C# tutorial on GDI+](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx)

or

check out [Libgdiplus](http://www.mono-project.com/Libgdiplus) for a cross platform version of GDI+

And this should get you started... obviously you wouldnt want to call new on your objects every time paint gets called...but you get the idea.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics g = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        Pen pen = new Pen(b, 20.5f);
        Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point p2 = new Point(this.Width, this.Height);

        g.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
    }


}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, isn't GDI+ a C++ library? I know nothing of C or C++, sadly... I'm just trying to make a working proof of concept GUI tool for a class project so I don't need anything robust.

Comment: No, he just gave you a bad link. Look over here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx and here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI

Answer (score 4):

The below code will draw a rectangle and display it in a picture box.
You could wire up an event to detect a resize and then redraw the rectangle.

```
Graphics GR;
Bitmap BM;
Rectangle myrect = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
Pen penTest = new System.Drawing.Pen(Brushes.Red);

using (GR = Graphics.FromImage(BM))
{
    GR.DrawRectangle(penTest, myrect);
}

picturebox1.Image = BM;
```